# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING In this Code

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, retrofit

I have a problem this in my android 
Json getting in postman is

```
{
    "syskey": "base64:5i/Sy3ujzpOhqTowu838H2gx2Uk4+LR4tLkK5eOZgfk=",
    "createDate": "",
    "updateDate": "",
    "data": {
        "market_mobile_banner": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "banner_txt": "banner1",
                "banner_price": "12.99",
                "banner_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/banner/PumdmssQTRKpAfyD7a6ai5NTCJJd7fFpOmCqKmPH.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "banner_txt": "banner2",
                "banner_price": "33.95",
                "banner_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/banner/X9sxhmREMRbyYV1poo2UnHUJKF9Bt6eQqcBL2LVn.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "banner_txt": "Banner3",
                "banner_price": "5.66",
                "banner_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/banner/4dGmwqiFB0V4qGfX1ZkEVFrILZUekvE0pPsjfCID.jpeg"
            }
        ],
        "whatsnew": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "new_txt": "new1",
                "new_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/new/Z1DB604SqG43tc3XJbJXxvqwES3H4BofMimnMVqP.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "new_txt": "new2",
                "new_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/new/FW39O5VLPvF4aBXd1UQwWWP3m6NLwx7IMSnYvHXk.jpeg"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "new_txt": "new3",
                "new_file": "https://webqr.saltcloudserver.com/storage/new/Srh5nCQekGLH9IPbmAkqwFV6pMou7yCXbkpWGp2l.jpeg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

GetHomeResponse.kt

```
data class GetHomeResponse(
    val syskey: String? = null,
    val createDate: String? = null,
    val updateDate: String? = null,
    val data: HomeData? = null)
```

HomeData.kt

```
data class HomeData(
     @SerializedName("market_mobile_banner")
     val marketMobileBanner: List<MarketMobileBannerItem?=null,
    val whatsnew: List<WhatsnewItem>?=null)
```

MarketMobileBannerItem.kt

```
data class MarketMobileBannerItem(
     val id: Int? = null,
     @SerializedName("banner_txt")
     val bannerTxt: String? = null,
     @SerializedName("banner_price")
     val bannerPrice: String? = null,
     @SerializedName("banner_file")
     val bannerFile: String? = null)
```

WhatsNewItem.kt

```
data class WhatsnewItem(
     val id: Int? = null,
     @SerializedName("new_txt")
     @Expose
     val newTxt: String? = null,
     @SerializedName("new_file")
     @Expose
     val newFile: String? = null)
```

WebQr.kt

```
interface WebQrApi {
  @GET("home/{outLetId}")
  fun getHomeData(@Path("outLetId") 
  outLetId:Int):Observable<GetHomeResponse>}
```

When I call it from my android code with retrofit , I have error 
`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 118 path $.data.whatsnew .`My Format is wrong or Server data is wrong?
This shows failure error .How can I fix ?
 My friend told that this is wrong in Json Format when adding attributes as collection.But it return as a String.

Comment: how are you parsing the response? you'll have to show the objects you're creating

Comment: I will edit this bro .Thanks for points

Answer (score 1):

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 118 path

Above error means that you are accessing as String instead of Array Json.

Solution :-  Try to access that variable using JsonArray.

Use these POJO in your retrofit...

> Data.class

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Data {

@SerializedName("market_mobile_banner")
@Expose
private List<MarketMobileBanner> marketMobileBanner = null;
@SerializedName("whatsnew")
@Expose
private List<Whatsnew> whatsnew = null;

public List<MarketMobileBanner> getMarketMobileBanner() {
return marketMobileBanner;
}

public void setMarketMobileBanner(List<MarketMobileBanner> marketMobileBanner) {
this.marketMobileBanner = marketMobileBanner;
}

public List<Whatsnew> getWhatsnew() {
return whatsnew;
}

public void setWhatsnew(List<Whatsnew> whatsnew) {
this.whatsnew = whatsnew;
}

}
```

> MarketMobileBanner.class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MarketMobileBanner {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("banner_txt")
@Expose
private String bannerTxt;
@SerializedName("banner_price")
@Expose
private String bannerPrice;
@SerializedName("banner_file")
@Expose
private String bannerFile;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getBannerTxt() {
return bannerTxt;
}

public void setBannerTxt(String bannerTxt) {
this.bannerTxt = bannerTxt;
}

public String getBannerPrice() {
return bannerPrice;
}

public void setBannerPrice(String bannerPrice) {
this.bannerPrice = bannerPrice;
}

public String getBannerFile() {
return bannerFile;
}

public void setBannerFile(String bannerFile) {
this.bannerFile = bannerFile;
}

}
```

> Result.class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Result {

@SerializedName("syskey")
@Expose
private String syskey;
@SerializedName("createDate")
@Expose
private String createDate;
@SerializedName("updateDate")
@Expose
private String updateDate;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

public String getSyskey() {
return syskey;
}

public void setSyskey(String syskey) {
this.syskey = syskey;
}

public String getCreateDate() {
return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
this.createDate = createDate;
}

public String getUpdateDate() {
return updateDate;
}

public void setUpdateDate(String updateDate) {
this.updateDate = updateDate;
}

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

> Whatsnew.class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Whatsnew {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("new_txt")
@Expose
private String newTxt;
@SerializedName("new_file")
@Expose
private String newFile;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getNewTxt() {
return newTxt;
}

public void setNewTxt(String newTxt) {
this.newTxt = newTxt;
}

public String getNewFile() {
return newFile;
}

public void setNewFile(String newFile) {
this.newFile = newFile;
}

}
```

**Use the `Result.class` for your retrofit interface method signature.**

Note:- It might be bcoz of your POJO class where you initialized a variable as `String` instead of `List<YourObject>`.

Try to covert your json into POJO using this [LINK](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/).

Comment: I will try this,Thanks

Comment: your response may be changing .

Answer (score 0):

**Your Base Model would be something like this**

```
public class MyPojo {

    @SerializedName("syskey")
    @Expose
    public String syskey;
    @SerializedName("createDate")
    @Expose
    public String createDate;
    @SerializedName("updateDate")
    @Expose
    public String updateDate;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    public Data data;

}
```

**And please once ensure this model you has used like below in API Interface**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api_url")
Call<MyPojo> callGetData(@FieldMap Map<String, String> method);
```

I hope after above thing ensure your error will be resolved

@Ptut I got something missing in your posted Model Code once check it

```
data class HomeData(
@SerializedName("market_mobile_banner")
val marketMobileBanner: List<MarketMobileBannerItem?=null,
val whatsnew: List<WhatsnewItem>?=null)
```

**You forgot to close List tag > of marketMobileBanner** so you new code something like below

```
data class HomeData(
@SerializedName("market_mobile_banner")
val marketMobileBanner: List<MarketMobileBannerItem>?=null,
val whatsnew: List<WhatsnewItem>?=null)
```

Comment: I will try this, Thanks

Comment: Above is just an example share you to ensure you have done something like that. I again see the error log and clearly indicate there second array "$.data.whatsnew" consider as a string so first, you can try with remove that later you need to do workaround near that.

Comment: I fixed it .I convert this JsonArray to ArrayList in server.And next fix is using JSonElement with changing custom.